# "Why you see this menu"

Tags: pharo

I broke something in my image (no idea what) and now my right-click menus only say "Why you see this menu, debug" -- what can I do to fix this ?

Comment: Which version of Pharo are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really tell what happened unless you do what that text tells you:

1. click on the menu entry
2. in the workspace that appears evaluate `menu debug`
3. post the contents of the debugger here

#### update

We need to find out what error is being signaled. Open the debugger again like you did, then select the first entry. Click on it with the right mouse button and select "Copy to clipboard" from the popup.
Post the stack trace in you clipboard here.

Alternative: Put the whole image somewhere I can download it and I'll take a peek.

#### update 2

The reason why `Smalltalk at: #Behavior put: Behavior` didn't change anything is that `Behavior` is a global reference equivalent to `Smalltalk at: #Behavior`. The effect is that you store the `RTGraphBuilder` class at the same location again :).

Try this:

```
Smalltalk at: #Behavior put: ClassDescription superclass
```

The superclass of `ClassDescription` is `Behavior` and that link is independent of the global lookup.

Comment: in the workspace that appears it says ""Something is wrong with this menu. 
To investigate just debug following expression:"
menu debug", when I evaluate menu debug, nothing happens. If I debug "menu debug", I get a debugger which if I step into it I get a FallbackMenu whos builder is a PragmaMenuBuilder ( nil ) for the method  debug [ builder menuSpec asMenuMorph ] ensure: [ builder reset ]. I'm using Pharo 3.0 and before it broke I was playing with visualizing object instances in Roassal using Object nextObject and SystemNavigator allObjectInstancesDo.

Comment: I can't do "copy to clipboard" in the debugger because the right-click menu I get is the same "why you see this menu"!

Comment: ...but the penultimate stack entry before DoesNotUnderstand is in extendedClasses of RPackage in the thenCollect: block, because Smalltalk globals at: #Behavior is a RTGraphBuilder, not Behavior :/ no idea how that happened...I tried Smalltalk at: #Behavior put: Behavior, but subsequently the same menu error still happens.

Comment: Smalltalk at: #Behavior put: ClassDescription superclass -- duh of course! Thankyou so much that fixed it :-)